# How to access language file inside config?

Tags: php, codeigniter, config

How we can use language file inside config.php php codeigniter? 
I searched to find solution just from out side the config we can set item in config to use language file for setting config item value, but how we can set config item using language file inside config file?
for example i want to do as bellow:

```
$config['item'] = array(
    '1' => $ci->lang->line('my_name')
);
```

Comment: That's all Alien *language* question to us without any code. Which *config* which *language* we have no clue :)

Comment: Sorry, but no idea what you're talking about. What `config.php`?

Comment: @Amadan Sorry, i use 'codeigniter', i want to use language file from within language folder inside 'config.php' file that is inside config folder

Comment: @ArifHussaini: The proper thing to do is to edit the post and add the `codeigniter` tag, so that people who have the relevant knowledge can see the post more easily (and people like me who have never touched it not to clutter the question). :)

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong way. You try make view function in config file. You can make this in template or may be in model.

You should change your application architecture.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access `ci` object in config file because this is load before `CI_Loader` class.
but you can update `config.php` field later on run time, using `$this->config->set_item('key', 'value');` function in **controller**/**model**/**library**

sample code in controller `__construct(){}` method

```
public function __construct(){
  $this->config->set_item('item', array('1' => $this->lang->line('my_name')));
}
```

Another way use [**hooks**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) to update item globally, more detail available on CI documentation.